# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in CountVectorizer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` exception in the following block of quote

```
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer().
    setInputCol("filtered").
    setOutputCol("countVector").
    setVocabSize(50000).
    setMinDF(20).
    fit(cleanedTokenized)
```

I am using Spark 2.0. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Unless you're doing something more than that it is probably a bug. Is it present in the 2.0.1?

Comment: That is the version I'm having this error in.